# Separate the html code in vb

Tags: html, vb.net

I got this piece of code which gets the html code from a URL inserted by the user.
The problem is that i want only parts of the html code.
The code:

```
  Dim URL_Request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
  Dim URL_Response As HttpWebResponse = URL_Request.GetResponse
  Dim Data_Stream As Stream = URL_Response.GetResponseStream
  Dim Stream_Reader As New StreamReader(Data_Stream)
  Dim ResponseFromServer As String = Stream_Reader.ReadToEnd
```

Is there any way to separate the code and work with only specific parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is commonly referred to as *[Web Scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)*.  You may want to do some searching on how to do web scraping with VB.NET.  There are already many examples of such programs online.  The most common method for this is to use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  It is an open source third-party library which allows you to parse HTML and query its data via XPATH.

Comment: I heard of it but couldn't find any vb examples...even not in msdn. Can you give me an example in vb ??thanks :)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with it myself, but there are [103 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-agility-pack+vb.net) right here on SO that are tagged with both VB.NET and Html Agility Pack.

Comment: I downloaded it and put it in the microsoft visual studio file but i cant do Imports HtmlAgilityPack....is there any options i need to change in order to use it?

Comment: You have to add a library reference to their dll.  Or a project reference to the project.